# Subsetting a data frame in a function using another data frame as parameter

Tags: function, r, dataframe

I would like to submit a data frame to a function and use it to subset another data frame.

This is the basic data frame:

```
foo <- data.frame(var1= c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3), var2=c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'))
```

I use the following function to find out the frequencies of `var2` for specified values of `var1`.

```
foobar <- function(x, y, z){
  a <- subset(x, (x$var1 == y))
  b <- subset(a, (a$var2 == z))
  n=nrow(b)
  return(n)
}
```

Examples:

```
foobar(foo, 1, "A") # returns 2
foobar(foo, 1, "B") # returns 1
foobar(foo, 3, "C") # returns 1
```

This works. But now I want to submit a data frame of values to `foobar`. Instead of the above examples, I would like to submit `df` to `foobar` and get the same results as above (2, 1, 1)

```
df <- data.frame(var1=c(1, 1, 3), var2=c("A", "B", "C"))
```

When I change `foobar` to accept two arguments like `foobar(foo, df)` and use `y[, c(var1)]` and `y[, c(var2)]` instead of the two parameters `x` and `y` it still doesn't work. Which way is there to do this?

**edit1:** last paragraph clarified

**edit2:** var1 type corrected

Comment: Quick formatting note - you can inline highlight text to be formatted as code with back-ticks "`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `foobar` is expecting three arguments, and you only supplied two arguments to it with `foobar(foo, df)`. You can use `apply` to get what you want:

`apply(df, 1, function(x) foobar(foo, x[1], x[2]))`

And in use:

```
> apply(df, 1, function(x) foobar(foo, x[1], x[2]))
[1] 2 1 1
```

**To respond to your edit:**

I'm not entirely sure what `y[, c(var1)]` means, but here's an attempt at trying to figure out what you are trying to do.

What I think you were trying to do was: `foobar(foo, y = df[, "var1"], z = df[, "var2"])`.

First, note that the use of `c()` is not needed here and you can reference the columns you want by placing the name of the column in quotes OR reference the column by number (as I did above). Secondly, `df[, "var1"]` returns all of the rows for the column names `var1` which has a length of three:

```
> length(df[, "var1"])
[1] 3
```

The function you defined is not set up to deal with vectors of length greater than 1. That is why we need to iterate through each row of your dataframe to grab a single value, process it, and then go to the next row in the data.frame. That is what the apply function does. It is equivalent to saying something along the lines of `for (i in 1: length(nrow(df))` but is a more idiomatic way of handling such issues.

Finally, is there a reason you generated `var1` as a factor? It probably makes more sense to treate these as numeric in my opinion. Compare:

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ var1: Factor w/ 2 levels "1","3": 1 1 2
 $ var2: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3
```

Versus

```
> df2 <- data.frame(var1=c(1,1,3), var2=c("A", "B", "C"))
> str(df2)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ var1: num  1 1 3
 $ var2: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3
```

In summary - `apply` is the function you are after here. You may want to spend some time thinking about whether your data should be numeric or a factor, but apply is still what you want.

Comment: @lecodesportif - I'm pretty sure the code above solves your problem. You need to process through your dataframe one row at a time. In processing one row at a time, we set the first column to `y` and the second column to `z`.

Comment: What I meant by `y[, c(var1)]` was simply that only `x` and `y` would be used in foobar instead of `x`, `y` and `z`. So `y` would be `df` within the function. You showed the correct way to address the columns `y[1]` and `y[2]`. I had some problems initially but it turned out to be caused by the variable type. You pointed that out, too. Also, your answer deserves no downvotes.

Comment: @lecodesportif - I can't tell you how many times I've tripped myself up with R's different data structures, especially when importing data from outside sources. I found [this](http://www.biw.kuleuven.be/vakken/statisticsbyr/someDataStructures.htm) quick read pretty helpful in keeping things straight. Good luck with the rest of your work!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
library(plyr)

match_df <- function(x, match) {
  vars <- names(match)

  # Create unique id for each row
  x_id <- id(match[vars])
  match_id <- id(x[vars])

  # Match identifiers and return subsetted data frame
  x[match(x_id, match_id, nomatch = 0), ]
}


match_df(foo, df)
#   var1 var2
# 1    1    A
# 3    1    B
# 5    2    C
```

Comment: I wasn't sure how general the function was supposed to be, so it will work with any two sets of data frames, although it really should check that all the columns in `match` are also in `x`.

Comment: And I'll probably add this function (once I think of a better name) to the next version of plyr - it's something I use all the time.

Answer (score 0):

```
foobar2 <- function(x, df) {
  .dofun <- function(y, z){
    a <- subset(x, x$var1==y)
    b <- subset(a, a$var2==z)
    n <- nrow(b)
    return (n)
  }
  ans <- mapply(.dofun, as.character(df$var1), as.character(df$var2))
  names(ans) <- NULL
  return(ans)
}
```